# what is Double here?

Tags: java, oop

I understand double as a variable type but in line 4 it might be used as datatype conversion. I just don't get the double used in line 6, am I completely missing the point here?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int discountPercentage = 10;
    double totalPrice = 800;
    double priceAfterDiscount = totalPrice * (1 - ((double) discountPercentage / 100));
    if (totalPrice > 500) {
        priceAfterDiscount = priceAfterDiscount * (1 - ((double) 5 / 100));
    }
    System.out.println("Customer has paid a bill of amount: "+ priceAfterDiscount);
}
```

Comment: Without the type cast, it's integer division.

Comment: Tip: Instead of casting, you could change those numeric literals from `int` to `double` by appending a `d` or `D`. Like this: `10d`, `800d`,  `500d`, `1d`, `5d`, and `100d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing `5 / 100` is an `int` division as both operand are `ints`, and in Java that will result in `0`.

See [Int division: Why is the result of 1/3 == 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/int-division-why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

---

To get `0.05`, you need to make a division with `double`

- define an operand as `double` explicitly

  ```
  5.0 / 100
  5 / 100.0
  ```
- cast an operand

  ```
  (double) 5 / 100
  5 / (double) 100
  ```